# how to draw a quadratic/cubic bezier curve in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, cubic-bezier

Supoose I have these points inkscape:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXkVp.png)

q=(1-t)^2 * p0 + 2 * t * (1-t) * p1 + t^2 * p2

c=(1-t)^3 * p0 + 3 * t * (1-t)^2 * p1 + 3 * (1-t) * t^2 * p2 + t^3 p3

I wanna draw this two cuves in inkscape.
p_i are control points.
I used the inkscape bezier tool, but the curve seems not the one I want.
Any one knows how to draw these two curves precisely?

Comment: Have a look a [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=50PXHb5STe8) on using the parametric curve extension.
Also note that this question is not about programming, so it may be voted to close. GraphicDesign stack exchange is a better place for this question.